# Pass url parameters to a embedded forms/iframes on landingpages

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, hubspot, typeform

I want to pass url parameters (hidden fields) to iframe/embedded forms on our Hubspot landing pages.

The url parameters I want to pass to the Typeform are `utm_source`, `email` and `referralcode`.

An example of a page I'm currently working on:

```html
<div class="typeform-widget"
     data-url="https://xxxxxx.typeform.com/to/xxxx"
     data-transparency="50"
     data-hide-headers=true
     data-hide-footer=true
     style="width: 100%; height: 600px;" > </div>

<script> (function() {
    var qs,js,q,s,d=document,
        gi=d.getElementById,
        ce=d.createElement,
        gt=d.getElementsByTagName,
        id="typef_orm",
        b="https://embed.typeform.com/";

    if (!gi.call(d,id)) {
        js=ce.call(d,"script");
        js.id=id;
        js.src=b+"embed.js";
        q=gt.call(d,"script")[0];
        q.parentNode.insertBefore(js,q)
    }
  })()
</script>
```

What code do I need to add to pass the url parameters to my embedded form?
Thanks

Comment: You could update the `data-url` attribute via javascript (element.setAttribute) to include them as GET parameters? However, there is no valid HTML form in your example, so I don't know if this will answer your question.

Answer (score 1):

This is possible using [Typeform Embed API](https://developer.typeform.com/embed)

See a [working example](https://tf-embed-with-params.glitch.me?utm_source=stackoverflow_question) on Glitch

You can edit [here](https://glitch.com/edit/#!/tf-embed-with-params).

Steps to reproduce:

1. Include Typeform Embed SDK in your HTML
2. Extract parameters from URL

   `let params = new URLSearchParams(location.search);`
3. Reconstruct your form URL

   `var url = "https://YOUR_SUBDOMAIN.typeform.com/to/YOUR_TYPEFORM_ID"
   url += "?utm_source=" + params.get('utm_source');`
4. Display form in a target `div`

   `const embedElement = document.querySelector('.target-dom-node')`
   `window.typeformEmbed.makeWidget(
     embedElement,
     url, 
     {
       hideHeaders: true,
       hideFooter: true,
     }
   )`

Hope it helps :)