# Pass Incoming URL Parameters to iframe src with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, post, get, parameter-passing

I have a Webflow form on my landing page that collects name, email, and phone number.  That form redirects to another page on my site that holds a full-screen TypeForm embed.

I'm trying to pass name, email, and phone to Typeform hidden fields with the GET method.

I'm really out of my element here... I have no idea what I am doing.  I've read many Stackoverflow threads and blog posts.

Am I close?  This is the code I have in my HTML embed.

```
<html> 

<head> 

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0"> 

<title>LBWR Qualification Form</title> 

<style type="text/css"> 

html{ margin: 0; height: 100%; overflow: hidden; } 
iframe{ position: absolute; left:0; right:0; bottom:0; top:0; border:0; } 

</style> 

</head> 

<body> 

<script type="text/javascript">

var loc = window.location.toString(),
    params = loc.split('?')[1],
    iframe = document.getElementById('typeform-full');

iframe.src = iframe.src + '?' + params;

</script>

<iframe id="typeform-full" width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0" src="https://zacharypinnell.typeform.com/to/k5BPk6">

</iframe> 

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://embed.typeform.com/embed.js">

</script> 

</body> 

</html>
```

I realize using GET may not be compliant-- it may not keep my leads' information safe.  Please feel free to redirect me in a different, more secure route, if you are feeling so kind.

Thank you very much in advance.

EDIT: Solved.

Answer (score 0):

That looks like a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49534280/pass-url-parameters-to-a-embedded-forms-iframes-on-landingpages/).

You could use [Typeform Embed SDK](https://developer.typeform.com/embed/), to have more control over your embed.

And retrieve the query parameters from the current page using javascript

`let params = new URLSearchParams(location.search);`

And then pass those parameters to typeform.

```
var url = "https://YOUR_SUBDOMAIN.typeform.com/to/YOUR_TYPEFORM_ID"
url += `?name=${params.get('name')}&email=${params.get('email')`;
```

But why not using a typeform for the first form too?